# Combinatorics Proof 3kCk

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I have trouble solving combinatorics proofs. I've looked at a bunch of textbook examples, but I never seem to figure out how to solve one on my own.

Right now, I am stuck with this one:

$\binom{3k}{k}$ = $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k+i}{k}\binom{2k-1-i}{k-1}$

I've been thinking maybe I can do something with the LHS being the collection of binary-strings with k 1's and 2k 0's,

So that would mean the RHS has to partition that in someway, 
I've seen solutions partitioning according to last occurence of a 1, or according to the number of 1's, positions in the string. But none of these seem applicable here.

Hints appreciated

Comment: @saulspatz I started suggesting that as a hint, but was only able obtain ${3k \choose k} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} {k+i \choose k}{2k-i \choose k}$. I'm curious how to obtain that final factor in the original post.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I stated the hint wrong.  I should have said that $i$ is the integer such that the $k$th zero occurs at bit number $2k-i$.

Comment: @saulspatz Now I see, thank you. Not sure if I misread the original, but I think the hint works either way.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I got it now :)